# Google Places API Web Service not the same results as Geocode API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

When using the following address:

> "107-25  CONTINENTAL AVE  Forest Hills NY 11375"

I get two different street numbers.

*Why is this?*

**Google Maps Geocoding API**

GET https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=

returns

```
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "107-12",
               "short_name" : "107-12",
               "types" : [ "street_number" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Continental Avenue",
               "short_name" : "Continental Ave",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Forest Hills",
               "short_name" : "Forest Hills",
               "types" : [ "neighborhood", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Queens",
               "short_name" : "Queens",
               "types" : [ "political", "sublocality", "sublocality_level_1" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Queens County",
               "short_name" : "Queens County",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "New York",
               "short_name" : "NY",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "United States",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "11375",
               "short_name" : "11375",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "107-12 Continental Ave, Forest Hills, NY 11375, USA",
```

when using the same address on

**Google Places API Web Service**

GET https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/js/PlaceService.GetPlaceDetails?

return:

```
  "address_components" : [
     {
        "long_name" : "107",
        "short_name" : "107",
        "types" : [ "street_number" ]
     },
     {
        "long_name" : "Continental Avenue",
        "short_name" : "Continental Ave",
        "types" : [ "route" ]
     },
     {
        "long_name" : "Forest Hills",
        "short_name" : "Forest Hills",
        "types" : [ "neighborhood", "political" ]
     },
     {
        "long_name" : "Queens",
        "short_name" : "Queens",
        "types" : [ "sublocality_level_1", "sublocality", "political" ]
     },
     {
        "long_name" : "Queens County",
        "short_name" : "Queens County",
        "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
     },
     {
        "long_name" : "New York",
        "short_name" : "NY",
        "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
     },
     {
        "long_name" : "United States",
        "short_name" : "US",
        "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
     },
     {
        "long_name" : "11375",
        "short_name" : "11375",
        "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
     }
  ]
```

Comment: The Places API and the Geocoder use different data sources.

Comment: @geocodezip thanks so much, why is this the case?

Comment: Not clear what did you send in second request. Was it place ID? Can you post the complete URLs of your requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to what has been briefly mentioned, the two different outputs - and we are really talking about a negligible numerical value that does not affect results anyway - show the two APIs are meant to address different purposes.

**Geocoding** is about turning human readable addresses into numerical coordinates and it should be used for [complete / unambiguous addresses.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/best-practices) Notice the precision of the returned results for ROOFTOPS. We are looking at an error of ~0.11 meters here.

This is like asking Google: "*Hey Google, give me the most relevant address for this string"*

[**Places API**](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search) in contrast...(for many people this may not be that obvious)

> allows you to query for place information on a variety of categories,
>   such as: establishments, prominent points of interest, geographic
>   locations, **and more**.

This is like asking: "*Hey Google, here you have a string, return everything in those categories and more*". In other words it is like receiving a mixed pot of a bit of everything...

Counter-intuitively we can deduce that there must be something in the string passed to the Places API that make the server turn the second number after the hyphen into a "slightly" different number and then return it.